# Error: The name 'Name' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, sql, if-statement

I've gone editing code -> which is never a good thing!

the code is for a file uploader in MVC. The thing was I was uploading two files at a time which meant they were inserted into separate rows in a database. This is the original code:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Convert your eBooks!";

        foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
        {
            if (!Request.Files[upload].HasFile1()) continue;

            string mimeType = Request.Files[upload].ContentType;
            Stream fileStream = Request.Files[upload].InputStream;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[upload].FileName);
            int fileLength = Request.Files[upload].ContentLength;
            byte[] fileData = new byte[fileLength];
            fileStream.Read(fileData, 0, fileLength);

            const string connect = @"Server=localhost;Database=Images;user id=taraw; password=siemensbs;";
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
            {
                var qry = "INSERT INTO FileStore (FileContent, MimeType, FileName) VALUES (@FileContent, @MimeType, @FileName)";
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileContent", fileData);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MimeType", mimeType);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", fileName);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Here is my attempt at modifying the code in order to take in the files separately as opposed to using a loop, and inserting them into a single row in a database table:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        if (!Request.Files["FileUpload1"].HasFile1())
        {
            string mimeTypePDF = Request.Files["FileUpload1"].ContentType;
            Stream fileStreamPDF = Request.Files["FileUpload1"].InputStream;
            string fileNamePDF = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files["FileUpload1"].FileName);
            int fileLengthPDF = Request.Files["FileUpload1"].ContentLength;
            byte[] fileDataPDF = new byte[fileLengthPDF];
            fileStreamPDF.Read(fileDataPDF, 0, fileLengthPDF);
        }

            if(!Request.Files["FileUpload2"].HasFile1())
        {
                string mimeTypeCover = Request.Files["FileUpload2"].ContentType;
                Stream fileStreamCover = Request.Files["FileUpload2"].InputStream;
                string fileNameCover = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files["FileUpload2"].FileName);
                int fileLengthCover = Request.Files["FileUpload2"].ContentLength;
                byte[] fileDataCover = new byte[fileLengthCover];
                fileStreamCover.Read(fileDataCover, 0, fileLengthCover);
        }

            const string connect = @"Server=localhost;Database=Images;user id=taraw; password=siemensbs;";
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
            {
                var qry = "INSERT INTO Book (FileContentPDF, MimeTypePDF, FileNamePDF, FileContentCover, MimeTypeCover, FileNameCover) VALUES (@FileContentPDF, @MimeTypePDF, @FileNamePDF, @FileContentCover, @MimeTypeCover, @FileNameCover)";
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileContentPDF", fileDataPDF);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MimeTypePDF", mimeTypePDF);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileNamePDF", fileNamePDF);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileContentCover", fileDataCover);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MimeTypeCover", mimeTypeCover);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileNameCover", fileNameCover);           
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        return View();
     }
```

Now I get the following errors for each cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue:

> The name 'fileDataPDF' does not exist
>   in the current context

I'm presuming this is because it is outside of the IF statements but I'm a bit stuck on how to structure it. I eventually want to use linq to insert the files into the database as the above method is not ideal, but my main aim for now is to just get this bit working. 
Any help would be appreciated greatly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the variables outside of the if conditional scopes. e.g.

```
    string mimeTypePDF;
    string fileNamePDF;
    byte[] fileDataPDF;

    if (!Request.Files["FileUpload1"].HasFile1())
    {
        mimeTypePDF = Request.Files["FileUpload1"].ContentType;
        Stream fileStreamPDF = Request.Files["FileUpload1"].InputStream;
        fileNamePDF = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files["FileUpload1"].FileName);
        int fileLengthPDF = Request.Files["FileUpload1"].ContentLength;
        fileDataPDF = new byte[fileLengthPDF];
        fileStreamPDF.Read(fileDataPDF, 0, fileLengthPDF);
    }
```

(Fwiw, I think there are better ways to handle this multifile upload, but the above is simplest way to handle your question.)

Comment: Hi Kaliatech, Yes I'm sure there must be. I've followed a tutorial and then tried to edit it myself which has made a mess of things !! :) I declared the variables outside the IF statement, however now the cmd.Parameters.AddWith value method is throwing the following error: "Use of unassigned local variable 'fileDataPDF'

Comment: You could bypass the compiler error by simply assigning a null value to the variable where it's declared: "byte[] fileDataPDF = null;". However, I wrote the answer as I did to highlight that if the conditional doesn't happen, then you might have problems later on in your code.  Depending on what you want to happen, you could also initialize the variable with "byte[] fileDataPDF = new byte[0]" to avoid the NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare fileDataPDF outside the if statement, otherwise its only visible to the if block.

Answer (score 0):

How about `byte[] fileDataPDF;` before if
and `fileDataPDF = new byte[fileLengthPDF];` inside if?